# How would i go about centering my 3 buttons on my web page?

Tags: html, css

i have 3 info buttons that show boxes about me, i want to center them on the page and line them up in a row, so instead of

button 1
button 2
button 3

i want...

button1 button2 button3

and i want the 3 of those to be in the center of the page, here's the code snippet im working with

```
      <p7><center><h2>Click a button below to show more about Jeremy!</h2></center></p7>
          <nav class="nav">
  <a href="https://prezi.com/p/xt95w1zae0ho/all-about-me-jeremy/" target="_blank">Prezi</a> 
</nav>
           <center><p><button class="button" font-size:="20px" onclick="myFunction()" id="button">About Me</button></p></center>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var myInfo = document.getElementById('demo');

    var displaySetting = myInfo.style.display;

    var clockButton = document.getElementById('button');

    if (displaySetting == 'block') {
      myInfo.style.display = 'none';
      clockButton.innerHTML = 'About Me';
    }
    else {
      myInfo.style.display = 'block';
      clockButton.innerHTML = 'Hide';
    }
  }
</script>
     <div id="demo" style="display:none"><font color="white"><b>Fav Color:</b> Orange/Purple<br><b>Hobbies:</b> Coding, Video games, Hanging out with friends, Drifting<br><b>Fav Song:</b> Homocide - Logic (ft. Eminem)<br><b>Fav Animal:</b> Cat<br><b>Fav Food:</b> Pulled Pork Sandwich</font></div>
</div>
      <center><p><button class="button2" font-size:="20px" onclick="myFunction2()" id="button2">Social Media</button></p></center>

<script>
  function myFunction2() {
    var myInfo2 = document.getElementById('demo2');

    var displaySetting2 = myInfo2.style.display;

    var clockButton2 = document.getElementById('button2');

    if (displaySetting2 == 'block') {
      myInfo2.style.display = 'none';
      clockButton2.innerHTML = 'Social Media';
    }
    else {
      myInfo2.style.display = 'block';
      clockButton2.innerHTML = 'Hide Social Media';
    }
  }
</script>
     <div id="demo2" style="display:none"><font color="white"><b>Discord:</b> Jeremy#2000<br><b>Snapchat:</b> pizzaraider<br><b>Instagram:</b> what_is_life__17</font></div>
<br>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far. So many ways to center buttons (`display: inline-block; text-align: center`, `flexbox`, `css-grid`...)

Comment: another thing, why make it so complicated to make the SPA approach? You can mimick it without any scripting by using `anchors` and `:targets` selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the display flex feature to center the buttons.

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.d-flex>button {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
  <button class="button" font-size:="20px" onclick="myFunction()" id="button">About Me</button>
  <button class="button2" font-size:="20px" onclick="myFunction2()" id="button2">Social Media</button>
  <button class="button3" font-size:="20px" onclick="myFunction3()" id="button2">Instagram</button>
</div>
```